# How do I display specific user details for my logged in user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the code I am trying to implement.

I want to return data for the user logged in, when I run a `listview` using this `datasource` without `WHERE UserName = @UserName` I get a full list of my users.

However, I want only to return the logged in users. With `WHERE UserName = @UserName` and my Select Parameters set I get null data returned - how do I change my `SELECT` statement to select data for my logged in user?

```
<asp:sqldatasource 
    id="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecondConnectionString %>"
    selectcommand="SELECT vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.UserId, vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.Email, vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.CreateDate, vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.LastLoginDate, vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.UserName, vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers.LastActivityDate
    WHERE UserName = @UserName">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter name="UserName" type="String" DefaultValue="LoggedInUser" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select parameter is probably never set. I suggest that you try to set the default value to something that exists in your database. If that makes a difference, you'll know that the parameter is never set to anything other than the default.

You can set the value of the parameter by using a controlparameter instead:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="__Page" Name="UserName" PropertyName="LoggedInUser" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

This will get the username from a property called LoggedInUser in the codebehind.

```
public string LoggedInUser
{
  get 
  {
    return "RJoness";
  }
}
```

Or you can set the parameter directly from codebehind:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("UserName", "RJoness");
```

Comment: Yeah, I realise that my parameter is wrong, if I set DefaultValue="RJoness" then I get that existing users data, which is what I want. What I don't know how to do is to pull the username of my logged in user pass that through as my parameter. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: edit to add example of getting parameter from codebehind

Comment: I have tried that an I am getting the error "Could not find control 'cparam' in ControlParameter 'UserName'." Does it matter that my code-behind is C# and not VB?

Comment: Sorry, you need to give the page as the controlId, I updated the answer